# How can we create Data aware dags for Bigquery?

Tags: python, google-bigquery, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I was going through new features of apache airflow,which includes creation of Data aware dags using Datasets.
I read multiple articles about it,but in every articles the dataset was either a Google cloud storage bucket or S3 bucket.
You can refer this article.
[https://medium.com/@MarinAgli1/a-look-into-airflow-data-aware-scheduling-and-dynamic-task-mapping-8c548d4ad79]

I want to know, is there any option to set dataset as a bigquery table.
I mean, whenever something happens to table, the dependent task or Dag should trigger.

Answer (score 0):

I think you miss misinterpret what it means.

In your example of S3 - Airflow does not actually query S3.
To qoute from the [AIP](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AIRFLOW/AIP-48+Data+Dependency+Management+and+Data+Driven+Scheduling) page:

> A Dataset can be thought of as an "opaque pointer" – or more specifically,
> Airflow is aware of it only at a high level, and (in this AIP) it
> doesn't understand anything about what the dataset actual is, where it
> lives or what data it contains. In other words, as far as Airflow is
> concerned a Dataset is just a name.

Airflow only marks a Dataset as updated when a task finishes successfully.
The Dataset name can be anything you want as long as you keep the URI format as explained in the [docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/authoring-and-scheduling/datasets.html#data-aware-scheduling). Thus if you have Airflow DAG that updates the BigQuery table then once it finish the Dataset entry is updated and depended DAGs will be scheduled.

Comment: then what is use of dataset. We can simply create two task ,one update the Table and other do stuffs after the table is updated. We can create dependency of task like this:  update_table >> do_other_task

Comment: And what if you have 50 other dags depending on this table? It allows you to write cleaner dags.